# BibTex and \includeonly command

Tags: bibtex

I have a document of this form

```
....

\includeonly{main}

\begin{document} 

   \include{main}

   \include{supp}

   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

I need LaTeX to read `supp.aux` for cross-referencing, but do not want BibTex to read `supp.aux`. In other words, I do not want to list `.bib` entries used in `supp.tex` to be included in the current document. Is there a way to direct BibTex to only look at `main.aux` and not `supp.aux`?

Answer (score 4):

If you compile your full document (no `\includeonly`) and ensure that all the cross references are OK, then you can reistate the `\includeonly` and LaTeX will load also the `.aux` files corresponding to the not included files.

Comment: I once had it working, but it is not working anymore. The issue is that when I run bibtex on the file with \includeonly, it apparently also looks at supp.aux and adds the corresponding bib entries to the references.

Comment: @passerby51 Why would you want that?

Comment: the issue is that I don't want bibliography of supp.tex to appear in the final version. Your suggestion does not seem to work.

Comment: @passerby51 Remove the `supp.aux` file (or rename it) and rerun BibTeX. If I had to do this I would simply write two papers or use `\input` and comment the unwanted one.

Comment: Thanks, writing two papers is not an option. I will try your suggestion which I think will work. What has worked for  now is to remove all .aux, .bbl, .etc files, comment out \include{supp} and run latex a couple of times, run bibtex, uncomment \include{supp} and comment out \includeonly{main}, run latex a couple and then uncomment \includeonly{main}, and run latex. I guess yours might be a better approach of doing this same thing

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing like egreg recomends, but before second compilation try deleting generated bibliography file that has the same name as the main file of your project, but has an extension `.bbl`. This will force bibtex to regenerate it but will exclude `supp` file.

As I remember, this worked for me when I was writing my master thesis.